# I enabled iptables logging from the command line. How do I undo this logging configuration?

Tags: iptables, logs

I ran

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j LOG --log-prefix "udp:"
```

How do I make it stop?

Comment: Have you looked at `man iptables` ?

Comment: If you're on a firewalld system, you might enjoy the [`--timeout` option](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding flag to delete a rule is `-D`; you can either use the same specification that you previously added or you can use the rule number.

To undo:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j LOG --log-prefix "udp:"
```

... use:

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT -p udp -j LOG --log-prefix "udp:"
```

... or find the rule number with:

```
iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers  # perhaps with a "|grep LOG" to narrow it down
```

receiving output *such as*:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
...
8    LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "udp:"
...
```

... you could then remove it with:

```
iptables -D INPUT 8
```

... where `8` is the "num" from the previous output that matches the rule you want to remove.